# Opera Turbo disables VPN extension's proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy, google-chrome-extensions, opera, chromium

I noticed that when using Opera Turbo feature, proxy that is set by VPN extension is disabled. Is there a way to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Turbo is a system which proxies all traffic through some proxy operated by Opera themselves, where the content is compressed back to the client.

This is how they provide the speed increase.  Since they are doing this though, they don't support connecting through another proxy,

http://help.opera.com/Mac/10.60/en/turbo.html